# Button inside a repeater is not functioning

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have two buttons inside of the repeater and I'm trying to access them from code behind, but they are not working. I receive the following error:

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

I don't understand what does the error mean nor where is coming from. Here is my code:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound1" 
        onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" >
    <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
    <tr>


        <td><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" /></td>
         <td><asp:Label ID="empnamelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fullname") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList></td>
        <td> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Present" CommandName="test1"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' /> </td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Absent"  CommandName="test2" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' /> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "test1")
    {
        Response.Write("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you Populating DropDownList dynamically ? When does the error show up..When you click button or when you select any value from dropdownlist ?

Comment: When I click any of the 2 buttons.

Comment: Ok. Show your Page Load code

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="attendance.aspx.cs" Inherits="attendance" %>

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         _connection.Open();
        
        OdbcCommand getempos = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * from empos", _connection);
        OdbcDataReader loopempos = getempos.ExecuteReader();

        Repeater1.DataSource = loopempos;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
        _connection.Close();
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using, UseSubmitBehavior="false", property in the buttons.

Here is it:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Text="Absent"  CommandName="test2" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `EnableViewState="false"` for the repeater. Definitely there will be some drawbacks but this has worked for me.

Else below are some more approaches you can try on:

If you  are setting your Repeater's DataSource in `Page_Load` event.

Try wrapping your Page_Load code inside `if(!IsPostBack)` .

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender , eventArgs e)
{
            if(!IsPostBack)
       {
             // bind repeater , dropdownlist items ... here
       }

}
```

Also from your error message it seems that `enableEventValidation=“true”` setting is present either in your Page as:

`<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" ... %>`

OR in your web.config :

```
<system.web>
   <pages enableEventValidation="true"/>
</system.web>
```

Some suggestions:

1. Disable eventvalidation. Easy to do but less secure .THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED. Also read here an extremely good article on this issue: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/22/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument-again.aspx
2. If any client side method is used to set changes in Controls, It's better to  use the 
   postback and add or remove the items server-side. Example: if a list control includes options numbered 1, 2, or 3 when the page is rendered, and if a postback request is received specifying option number 4, ASP.NET raises an exception.

This [MSDN reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx) is good too.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

due to presence of Image that run at server .. try to use img tag instead

Comment: I removed it and still no luck!

Comment: you should use if(!Page.IsPostBack) before populating data in your page load event